# Pushing image to shared private repo

Tags: docker

My boss created private repository with name `boss/project`, granted access to me.

Then I created `image` named `boss/project`, and trying:

```
docker tag image_id boss/project:v0.01
docker push boss/project:v0.01
```

Docker web site shows me, that last activity of reposity was a few seconds ago, but the `repo` was updated 4 days ago.


Than my boss trying to

```
docker pull boss/project:v0.01
```

and get the error:

```
Error: image boss/project:v0.01 not found
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The answer - he was not logined, what's why `image not found`

Comment: i ran into that too. i found that if i use a Dockerfile, checked in to github, and auto build the image, then i don't have to be logged in to 'see' it.   there is probably some way of making the image visible even if you aren't logged in. i don't know how, though :-(